# How can I properly match a private message on IRC?

Tags: python, regex, irc

I'm making a irc lib and I can't seem to match just private messages, it also matches the version string.

**REGEX**

```
:(?P<from>.*?)!\S+\sPRIVMSG\s(?P<to>.*?)\s:(?P<msg>.+)
```

**VERSION MATCH**

```
VERSION_STRING: :AkaneSenri1!~AkaneSenr@72A6C9FC.264941B0.A6596FAF.IP PRIVMSG AkaneSenri1 :VERSION
MATCHED: AkaneSenri1', u'AkaneSenri1', u'\x01VERSION\x01
PRIVATE_MESSAGE_STRING: :AkaneSenri1!~AkaneSenr@72A6C9FC.264941B0.A6596FAF.IP PRIVMSG AkaneSenri1 :T
MATCHED: (u'AkaneSenri1', u'AkaneSenri1', u'T') # is what I want
```

What I'm getting is the version string that that the server sends when you connect.
What I need is, when a user sends the bot a PM. (nick/msg)

Comment: Can you show us what you're getting and what you expect?

Comment: Maybe [`:(?P<from>.*?)!\S+\sPRIVMSG\s(?P<to>.*?) :(?!VERSION$)(?P<msg>.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bS4sN1/2)? (Note I used the `re.M` modifier for `$` to match the end of the line, not string)

Comment: it still seems to be matching the version string

Comment: you have to use the 'm' (multiline match) - Wiktor's regex appears to be fine for your input.

Comment: [`:(?P<from>.*?)!\S+\sPRIVMSG\s(?P<to>.*?) :(?!VERSION)(?P<msg>.+)`?](https://regex101.com/r/bS4sN1/3) Please define a version string.

Comment: I did, but I split at the line ending `\r\n` so when the data passes it comes line by line. Therefore, adding re.M wouldn't do anything right? But I did add it just in case.

Comment: That is why you should post the code you are using. You don't need the `re.M`, but the former pattern should work fine if version strings end with `VERSION`.

Comment: `AkaneSenri1', u'AkaneSenri1', u'\x01VERSION\x01` that is the version string sent when I connect.

Comment: Then add these \x01 to the lookahead: `:(?P<from>.*?)!\S+\sPRIVMSG\s(?P<to>.*?) :(?!\u0001VERSION\u0001)(?P<msg>.+)` or `:(?P<from>.*?)!\S+\sPRIVMSG\s(?P<to>.*?) :(?!\u0001VERSION\u0001$)(?P<msg>.+)`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/sb5SqVxJ just comment out `import errors` and all the raise statements, it will run. That is what I have, but won't the version string change depending on the server?

Comment: We cannot tell you what data you have. Only you can know that and let us know. Otherwise, your question is *unclear*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:(?P<from>.*?)!\S+\sPRIVMSG\s(?P<to>.*?)\s+:(?!VERSION)(?P<msg>.*)$
```

It's looking for `: not followed by VERSION` with a negative lookahead `(?!...)`

See it here: https://regex101.com/r/sQ7eS6/2 (click on the unit tests bit on the left, then run both tests. Or paste your lines into the main bit)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/sb5SqVxJ just comment out `import errors` and all the raise statements, it will run. It still does the version.

Comment: @MichaelBorgfield You can't paste an example string which causes you a problem, but you can share your username and password with the world? Hmm.

Comment: I posted the exact message the server sends, I also gave the complete lib so you would see. Did you want a complete log?

Comment: I have no idea why this isn't working, I did use a website similar to the one you used. I got a positive match, but for whatever reason it doesn't seem to work when applying to the lib.